# I think CSS3 transform translateZ is equal to scale by some means

Tags: html, css, transform, scale

In some case, I think the `translateZ` and `scale` have the same effect ,just like zoom in or zoom out.

I think there are some calculate connection between them, if I konw one value of them, like `translateZ(-1000px)` and the parent `perspective` value, can I calculate the `scale` value that have the same effect equal to the `translateZ` ?

Comment: That's probably more of a math question that it is programming

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You are correct. As an object moves towards you (i.e. `translateZ`) it appears larger (i.e. `scale`).

As shown in this diagram, `perspective` defines where the viewer is relative to the container and `translateZ` defines where the subject is relative to the container.

> [image: diagram of translateZ]

The formula to go from scale to translateZ (and back):

[image: scale=perspective/(perspective-translateZ)] -OR- [image]

I'll leave the mathematical proof to a math whiz, but I did some checking with the [pythagorean theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) and everything works out.

#### Example:

Let's say you're 100px from the container: `#container { perspective: 100px; }`

1. If you `translateZ(50px)`, the subject has moved halfway to you and will appear twice as large, making it 2x.
2. If you `translateZ(75px)`, the subject has moved *another* halfway closer and will double again, making it 4x.
3. If you keep doing this, as you get closer to `translateZ(100px)`, the subject will approach being to infinitely large.

Try it out. Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ansonhoyt/83jtA/) to compare different examples visually.

#### Limits:

This works if the subject is moving directly towards you, but falls apart if you do things like rotate the subject in 3D space. There is math for that too, but it gets complicated. Check out [3D Projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection) on wikipedia.